# Convert JSON to plist use PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, plist

convert JSON to plist have many ways, The most convenient is to use commands under the apple system, or to use online generation tools, But PowerShell does not provide direct commands, I found a project in GitHub, which can be easily converted for simple JSON, But for some slightly complex JSON, there will be some problems after conversion

project Address:https://github.com/msftrncs/PwshJSONtoPList

**Existing problems:**

Some arrays were not converted correctly

I recorded a video demo https://www57.zippyshare.com/v/krihd4Y8/file.html

related files https://www57.zippyshare.com/v/84wYYTRx/file.html

**powershell Script code:**

```
. '.\ConvertTo-PList.ps1' # Put ConvertTo-PList.ps1 in the same directory
Get-Content "test.json" | ConvertFrom-Json |
ConvertTo-Plist -Indent "`t" -StateEncodingAs 'UTF-8' |
Set-Content 'Generated.plist' -Encoding 'UTF8'
```

**test.json:**

```
{
  "ACPI": {
    "DSDT": {
      "Debug": false,
      "DropOEM_DSM": false,
      "Fixes": {
        "AddDTGP": false,
        "FixHPET": false,
        "FixRTC": false,
        "FixShutdown": false
      },
      "Patches": [
        {
          "Comment": "change SAT0 to SATA",
          "Disabled": false,
          "Find": "U0FUMA==",
          "Replace": "U0FUQQ=="
        },
        {
          "Comment": "change HECI to IMEI",
          "Disabled": false,
          "Find": "SEVDSQ==",
          "Replace": "SU1FSQ=="
        }
      ],
      "ReuseFFFF": false
    },
    "DropTables": [
      {
        "Signature": "DMAR"
      },
      {
        "Signature": "MATS"
      }
    ],
    "FixHeaders": true,
    "SSDT": {
      "DropOem": false,
      "Generate": {
        "CStates": true,
        "PStates": true
      }
    }
  },
  "GUI": {
    "Custom": {
      "Entries": [
        {
          "Disabled": false,
          "FullTitle": "MAC OS X",
          "Hidden": false,
          "InjectKexts": true,
          "NoCaches": true,
          "Type": "OSX",
          "Volume": "2D4A5E3A-04FC-3041-471B-8A1622089D19"
        },
        {
          "Disabled": false,
          "FullTitle": "WIN",
          "Hidden": false,
          "Type": "Windows",
          "Volume": "2BDB20A2-1E67-4AE2-753D-D85E9A410000"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Hide": [
      "Preboot",
      "Recovery",
      "BOOTX64.EFI",
      "DATA"
    ]
  },
  "KernelAndKextPatches": {
    "ForceKextsToLoad": [
      "\\System\\Library\\Extensions\\IONetworkingFamily.kext"
    ],
    "KextsToPatch": [
      {
        "Comment": "External icons patch",
        "Disabled": false,
        "Find": "RXh0ZXJuYWw=",
        "InfoPlistPatch": false,
        "Name": "AppleAHCIPort",
        "Replace": "SW50ZXJuYWw="
      },
      {
        "Comment": "Enable TRIM for SSD",
        "Disabled": false,
        "Find": "AEFQUExFIFNTRAA=",
        "InfoPlistPatch": false,
        "Name": "com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage",
        "Replace": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Generated.plist:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ACPI</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DSDT</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Debug</key>
            <false/>
            <key>DropOEM_DSM</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Fixes</key>
            <string>@{AddDTGP=False; FixHPET=False; FixRTC=False; FixShutdown=False}</string>
            <key>Patches</key>
            <string> </string>
            <key>ReuseFFFF</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>DropTables</key>
        <array>
            <string>@{Signature=DMAR}</string>
            <string>@{Signature=MATS}</string>
        </array>
        <key>FixHeaders</key>
        <true/>
        <key>SSDT</key>
        <dict>
            <key>DropOem</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Generate</key>
            <string>@{CStates=True; PStates=True}</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>GUI</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Custom</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Entries</key>
            <string> </string>
        </dict>
        <key>Hide</key>
        <array>
            <string>Preboot</string>
            <string>Recovery</string>
            <string>BOOTX64.EFI</string>
            <string>DATA</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>KernelAndKextPatches</key>
    <dict>
        <key>ForceKextsToLoad</key>
        <array>
            <string>\System\Library\Extensions\IONetworkingFamily.kext</string>
        </array>
        <key>KextsToPatch</key>
        <array>
            <string>@{Comment=External icons patch; Disabled=False; Find=RXh0ZXJuYWw=; InfoPlistPatch=False; Name=AppleAHCIPort; Replace=SW50ZXJuYWw=}</string>
            <string>@{Comment=Enable TRIM for SSD; Disabled=False; Find=AEFQUExFIFNTRAA=; InfoPlistPatch=False; Name=com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage; Replace=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=}</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**err Pic:**
[image]

Comment: Seems like the proper response is to file an issue on the GitHub project. Unless you’ve somehow determined this to be an issue caused by powershell?

Comment: Indeed, it may be some problems with the author's source code. I hope someone can point out and solve them. I will give feedback later

Answer (score 3):

The version I see [here](https://github.com/msftrncs/PwshJSONtoPList/blob/master/ConvertTo-PList.ps1) also has a `-Depth` parameter.

If I use that on your json and set the Depth to 4 (or higher) with

```
$json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Plist -Indent "`t" -StateEncodingAs 'UTF-8' -Depth 4
```

it produces this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ACPI</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DSDT</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Debug</key>
            <false/>
            <key>DropOEM_DSM</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Fixes</key>
            <dict>
                <key>AddDTGP</key>
                <false/>
                <key>FixHPET</key>
                <false/>
                <key>FixRTC</key>
                <false/>
                <key>FixShutdown</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>Patches</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Comment</key>
                    <string>change SAT0 to SATA</string>
                    <key>Disabled</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>Find</key>
                    <string>U0FUMA==</string>
                    <key>Replace</key>
                    <string>U0FUQQ==</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Comment</key>
                    <string>change HECI to IMEI</string>
                    <key>Disabled</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>Find</key>
                    <string>SEVDSQ==</string>
                    <key>Replace</key>
                    <string>SU1FSQ==</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>ReuseFFFF</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>DropTables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Signature</key>
                <string>DMAR</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Signature</key>
                <string>MATS</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>FixHeaders</key>
        <true/>
        <key>SSDT</key>
        <dict>
            <key>DropOem</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Generate</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CStates</key>
                <true/>
                <key>PStates</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>GUI</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Custom</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Entries</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Disabled</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>FullTitle</key>
                    <string>MAC OS X</string>
                    <key>Hidden</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>InjectKexts</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NoCaches</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>Type</key>
                    <string>OSX</string>
                    <key>Volume</key>
                    <string>2D4A5E3A-04FC-3041-471B-8A1622089D19</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Disabled</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>FullTitle</key>
                    <string>WIN</string>
                    <key>Hidden</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>Type</key>
                    <string>Windows</string>
                    <key>Volume</key>
                    <string>2BDB20A2-1E67-4AE2-753D-D85E9A410000</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>Hide</key>
        <array>
            <string>Preboot</string>
            <string>Recovery</string>
            <string>BOOTX64.EFI</string>
            <string>DATA</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>KernelAndKextPatches</key>
    <dict>
        <key>ForceKextsToLoad</key>
        <array>
            <string>\System\Library\Extensions\IONetworkingFamily.kext</string>
        </array>
        <key>KextsToPatch</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Comment</key>
                <string>External icons patch</string>
                <key>Disabled</key>
                <false/>
                <key>Find</key>
                <string>RXh0ZXJuYWw=</string>
                <key>InfoPlistPatch</key>
                <false/>
                <key>Name</key>
                <string>AppleAHCIPort</string>
                <key>Replace</key>
                <string>SW50ZXJuYWw=</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Comment</key>
                <string>Enable TRIM for SSD</string>
                <key>Disabled</key>
                <false/>
                <key>Find</key>
                <string>AEFQUExFIFNTRAA=</string>
                <key>InfoPlistPatch</key>
                <false/>
                <key>Name</key>
                <string>com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage</string>
                <key>Replace</key>
                <string>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Apparently you have an older version of the script.

Comment: There is also a small problem, not < string >, is< data > see pic:  https://i.ibb.co/mNsf4SR/pic.png

Comment: @tianyi Well, if you don't want those tags to be called `<string>`, just alter line 78 of the script from `"$indention<string>$($item | writeXMLcontent)</string>"` to `"$indention<data>$($item | writeXMLcontent)</data>"`.

Comment: It is still impossible to change all <string> tags to <data> tags, need change only the fields of 【* * * =】see pic. https://i.ibb.co/JdMSdbv/pic.png

Comment: @tianyi Well, I'm sorry but I'm not the author of that function. Also, there seems to be no logic in what tags you want to keep as `<string>` as opposed to the others that you wish to turn into `<data>`.. Should be an easy fix though, just insert an `if` in the code and add your own condition to decide what tag to use.

Comment: Thank you for your help, do you know the data 【U0FUMA==】of this format?

Comment: @tianyi `U0FUMA==` is a string. Judging by the `=` characters at the end, probably a Base64 encoded string. In fact, if I decode that it reads `SAT0`